# Is the following function even, odd or neither?

Tags: functions, even-and-odd-functions

Is the following function even, odd or neither ?

$$[2x]$$

Shall I divide the argument into when it belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$ and when it belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Z}$?And what about if the argument inside the step function is a trigonometric function ?

thanks!

Comment: Simply calculate $f(-x)$ and see whether it is equal to $\pm f(x).$ Yes, you may find it helpful to consider integer and non-integer arguments.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  but the value of f(-x) depends on what is x.

Comment: of course it does but to be even (or odd) $f(-x)$ must equal $f(x)$ (or $-f(x)$) for *all* $x.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's not even because $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$, where as $f(-\frac{1}{2})=-1$.
- It's not odd, because $f(0.1)=0$ where as $-f(-0.1)=-(-1)=1$.

Comment: But if I studied it as a cases as I mentioned in the question, I think the answer will be different ......right ?... here you are considering non integer cases.

Comment: but your answer did not answer the OP question .... could you clarify the points mentioned by the OP please?

Comment: @Idonotknow Maybe the answer differs when you consider integer cases. I don't know. But it's good to think about it :) It shouldn't be hard.